# How to make a stylized low-poly tube tree?

Tags: modeling

So, I want to make a tree something like this:

[image]

However, I don't want the fur/hair on it. I want the tree to be made
using tubes and as seen in the image the same tube(s) in the stump should branch out and form the branches.
Also, each branch should reduce in thickness as it extends to it's end.
I'm making this for a game asset,hence I need it as low-poly as possible.

Comment: Use the skin modifier

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Tried doing that..doesn't work the way I want. how do i get it to twist around itself at specific points?

Comment: Not sure if skin supports tilting, otherwise adjust it after converting to mesh

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos could you show me how?

Comment: Try this video: [Make a rope in Blender](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiLv-XUitrYAhUMvrwKHaCoCh4QtwIIKDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D1drRNphACMc&usg=AOvVaw3Nzm1kIw28j9naHvhS-H5s)

Comment: That changes the mesh in the render..not physically, I wont be able to take it into a game engine.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I tried your method, but couldn't get it to work

Comment: I've been testing and the *Skin* modifier does not support tilting. So to get the twisted surface either use a bezier curve object instead, if you don't need a continuous surface, or deform it afterwards using *Proportional Edit*, or a *Lattice* or *Simple Deform* or any other method to your liking

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos sounds promising, could you show it to me in detail?

Comment: Related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132623/modeling-a-twisty-tree-how-do-i-twist-a-beveled-curve