# How to make a rope curving in a certain way

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I wanted to make a small rope curving like this in Blender for my model. But I found 2 issues; I can't find a way how to curve this smoothly (so tips for bezier curve or whatever would be appreciated) and if I already make something looking at least 70% like I want it, when I apply the curve modifier the rope just disappear and it is nowhere to be found.
[image]
How can I do it?

Comment: If you share the file it's easier for us to find out what went wrong.

Comment: If you use an array for the rope, then maybe change around the modifier order, then the mesh might stop disappearing

Comment: Just an idea: Maybe a starting point could be using two mesh (not curve type) circles, which you then later convert to curve type (with Alt+c -> mesh to curve). Then after deleting vertices and connecting both circles, you might then change some of the interpolation settings (e.g. order) of the curve object to make it smooth.

Comment: This answer includes your usecase I think: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/132690/60924

Answer (score 7):

It's easy to lose bits if their origins aren't in the right place. Here's one approach to your job: I hope the loops are circular enough for you. Working in the XY plane..

**The curve:**

(As suggested by @Robert Roth)

1. Make an unfilled 6-sided mesh circle, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicate it in Edit Mode, <kbd>X</kbd> delete a couple of edges, and <kbd>F</kbd> join the loose ends.
2. Then, in Object Mode, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> convert the mesh to a curve. With all vertices selected,  In the Tool region, set the Spline Type to Bezier, and <kbd>V</kbd> convert all the vertices to 'Auto'

There may be a bit of tweaking to do...

[image]

Note where the origin of the curve is: at world 0. When you create the profile / set up your rope, to make things easier, put its origin at the same place. Make sure all object-level transforms of the rope (especially scale) are applied.

**The rope:**
(For example)

1. A little trefoil profile, made out of 3 6-sided unfilled circles, snapped together, doubles removed, internal edges removed.
2. With all vertices selected, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>Set Origin to geometry, and set the transform of the profile object to (0,0,0) Now everything is lined up.
3. Screw modifier, 120 degrees
4. Array modifier, relative Z, Merge on, Count to fit the curve.
5. Curve modifier, Deformation Axis Z, target: the curve
6. Subdivision modifier, level 1

[image]

With this sort of result:

[image]

EDIT: (response to @Teglik)

You can manipulate the path-mesh in various ways: here, working on the left half, <kbd>E</kbd> extending terminal vertices, and <kbd>R</kbd> rotating and  <kbd>S</kbd> scaling the new vertices in/out from the 3D cursor at the origin, before duplicating and rotating the whole left half through 180 to make the right half, <kbd>F</kbd> joining the ends, before converting to a curve.

[image]

Comment: (Blender 2.8) - It is just too sharp at all, it's not looking like a circle, and the way of the curve is at both of the ends the same (going in), so there are 2 ways of the curve.

Comment: That would just be an adjustment to the path mesh, before conversion to a curve, maybe a few more vertices, a deeper overlap? Or even connecting Mesh: Extra Objects (shipped add-on) spirals rather than circles? .. Will edit when I can ..

Comment: @Teglik is that more like it?