# How to make a screw fallow a curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

How can i make a screw object fallow a curve correctly? I am trying to make something like a tape around a torus and it only works for a part of the curve.
increasing the angle on screw doesn't work. Increasing the curve smoothness doesn't work. What is the correct way to make such an object?

[image]

Comment: does [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/146410/35559) help?.. maybe you're after something else ...

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57615/how-can-i-model-these-support-wires/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58959/how-to-model-braided-nylon-sleeve/58963

Comment: @Robin Betts That worked. But the path is a perfect circle. Is there a way to have the screw fallow a different shape like this one [link](https://imgur.com/opum7MB)  i am trying to make a rib that is bulge on sides and smaller on top and bottom.

Comment: @GigelVasilica One way to that (see [here](https://imgur.com/a/ef2fIIV)) would be to start with a Bezier-Circle, or a mesh with more vertices converted, and Alt-S, or in the _Item > Transform_  panel, alter the radius of selected vertices..