# Help with adding 'ribbing' to a 3D Modelled horn

Tags: modeling

So I'm trying to add 'ribbing' to these horns, I know I can manually go in and just create the geometry, but I didn't know if there was an easier method for adding that kind of detail to a model?

The horns have been created by starting with a cylinder, and just extruding it to shape then I've added a level 2 subsurf modifier to it, so I can get a better idea on how it'll look

Any advice would be appreciated!

[image: What I'm trying to model]
[image: Where I'm currently up to]

Comment: Read: [modeling a twisty tree, how do I twist a beveled curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132623/modeling-a-twisty-tree-how-do-i-twist-a-beveled-curve)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1drRNphACMc

Comment: Ahh thank you, I shall give this a go =)